# rosjava for Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
Is someone already using rosjava on Fuerte? How can I install these packages like rosjava_bootstrap,.etc.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45026/rosjava-for-fuerte-on-ubuntu-12.04/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2012-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently using rosjava and rosjava.android on a 12.04 install, the documentation can be found at

[Rosjava Install Documentation](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/index.html)

That should walk you through the install process for everything, as well as get you started.

---

Originally posted by [Jyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2115/jyo/) with karma: 100 on 2012-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-04**:
Hey...thanks. I have yesterday tried it from link http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html but it gives "ERROR: Ambiguous workspace: ROS_WORKSPACE=/home/safdar/rosrescue, /home/safdar/my_workspace/.rosinstall". Did you alsoinstall rosjava on Fuerte on ubuntu 12.04???

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-04**:
Hi joy! I have solved Ambigugous problem. I seemed to me that all steps are gone correctly. Now when I rosmake a rosjava based package then I get error [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rosenv'] , Do you know why do I get this error?

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-10-10**:
rosjava does not support rosmake. I suggest going back to the documentation and making sure you can build and run the pubsub tutorial.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-21**:
I get ERROR:Unzipping /home/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin/7ilkmgo2rn79vvfvd51rqf17ks/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin.zip to /home/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-9-bin/7ilkmgo2rn79vvfvd51rqf17ks
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-10-23**:
I imagine you have a corrupt download. Delete the zip file and try again.

**Comment by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on 2012-10-23**:
its fine now. But if I run ../gradlew installApp from rosjava_tutorial_pubsub it builds successfully but I dont see any bin directory. if I run ./build/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/bin/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub org.ros.rosjava_tutorial_pubsub.Talker then it gives error Data not found. how can I run Talker?

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-10-23**:
Please post a new question with your issue. Also, be sure to follow the rosjava tutorials: http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#executing-nodes